# How to set width of ImageButton when setting the background image larger in android?

Tags: android, width, imagebutton

I want to programmatiacally set the larger Image as background of ImageButton in Android and set its height and width as fixed. I am able to create the Image Button as follow. But the Image comes larger as its size. How to fix its size according to the button's size.

```
ImageButton b0=new ImageButton(this);
b0.setMaxWidth(100);
b0.setMinimumWidth(100);
b0.setMaxHeight(80);
b0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tattoo0);
tattooListView.addView(b0);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code helped me to achieve my target.

```
     ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
     String str=String.format("drawable/theimage");
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(str, null, getPackageName());

    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 80, true); 

            btn.setBackgroundColor(80000000);
            btn.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            btn.setTag(1);

            linearlayoutview.addView(btn);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
b0.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: OK, then you can try using setBackgroungDrawable() instead of setBackgroundResource()

Comment: simply change b0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tattoo0);
for b0.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.tattoo0);

Answer (score 1):

ScaleType Wont work for Background it will work for Source Image. Source image you can set By src property in xml, or programmatically by setImage() methods as below:

[public void setImageBitmap (Bitmap bm)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

[public void setImageDrawable (Drawable drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

[public void setImageResource (int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29)

Comment: How can we use setimage() to set the Backgroud image of the button?